# Why @Query are not getting executed in Spring Boot Data JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-query

I have a Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRequestRepository extends JpaRepository<UserRequestDao, Long> {

@Query("SELECT ur FROM UserRequestDao ur WHERE ur.user.id = ?1")
    //@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USER_REQUEST WHERE USER_ID = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<UserRequestDao> findAllByUserId(long id);
}
```

In both cases (first @Query and the second native @Query) the Hibernate executes the following query:

```
select v1_0.id,v1_0.cel_id,v1_0.user_id,v1_0.instructions,v1_0.occasion from user_request v1_0
```

That is to retrieve all user requests. Why is Hibernate ignoring the @Query and why is it retrieving all records, when I added the @Query annotation? It should retrieve the records based on the user id.

Here is the DAO object:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@Table(name = "USER_REQUEST")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserRequestDao {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private UserDao user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private CelebDao celeb;

    private String occasion;
    private String instructions;
}
```

Here is the service class from where I'm calling the repository method:

```
@Override
public List<VideoRequest> getAllByUserId(Long id) {
    List<VideoRequestDao> videoRequests = repository.findAllByUserId(userService.get(id).getId());
    return videoRequests.stream().map(ObjectConverter::convertToVideoRequestModel).toList();
}
```

I have tried to figure it out mostly by searching online but could not find a solution.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: It seems odd that you are presumably fetching the user by id using the userService. I'm not quite sure why you would do that if you already have the (Long id). Why not just directly pass the id like: repository.findAllByUserId(id)? It almost seems like JPA is using a different query because of this but it's hard to tell. 

Can you post the UserService class as well as the UserDao class?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no mistake in the @Query implementation, so my guess is, on the @Service layer, you must have called the findAll() method instead of findAllByUserId(long id).

Comment: Nope, I do call the correct method from the service class. I just added a snippet to the question. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, But your repository returns List<UserRequestDao> and your service class implementation is accepting List<VideoRequestDao>. Was the class name changed?

Comment: Yes, that is my bad during the copy/paste.